# imacros: Find frame button is in WITHOUT pressing the button

Tags: javascript, imacros

FF 42.0 / Imacros for FF BUILD=8940826 / 2.8Ghz 8 core Early 2008 MacPro / OSX 10.8.2

I've got a js function that finds the frame containing a given button and returns the frame number.

```
function findFrame()
{

   var frameCheck =  "CODE:";
   frameCheck =  "SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0";
   frameCheck+=  "FRAME F={{i}}" + "\n"; 
   frameCheck+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button" + "\n"; 

   frame=1;

   for(i=1;i<=25;i++){
      iimSet("i",i)

     //if the result of the macro is true save frame number and break
     if(iimPlay(frameCheck)==true){

        frame=i;
        break;
     }
   }
   //return frame number
   return frame;


}
```

However, there are a number of things I want to do within that frame once I find it, so I'd like to separate the search from the button press so can put the button press into a macro along with the other things that need to happen in that frame.

All the examples I've been able to dig up about seeking a button also press that button.  I'm assuming it's just this line that needs to change:

```
frameCheck+=  "TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button" + "\n";
```

but I'm not sure how to search for the existence of something without interacting with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ret=iimPlayCode("TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER");
if (ret == false)
    // not found
else
    // found
```

Second type would be using event for hovering over mouse. :D

Answer (score 0):

As an example, you can search for the existence of something without interacting with it in this way:

```
iimPlayCode("TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON ATTR=DATA-LOG-CLICK:add-button EXTRACT=TXT");
if (iimGetExtract() == "#EANF#")
    // not found
else
    // found
```

Comment: hmmm.... this returns wrong (premature) frame number on site I'm currently working on.  I'd have to dig in more to find out why, but CONTENT=EVENT:MOUSEOVER is landing on the right one.  Not familiar enough to know if some options may work better for certain situations than others.

Comment: According to your function logic, my code must work correctly with a positive condition: `… if (iimGetExtract() != "#EANF#") { // found } else 
{ // not found }` . However the way with `EVENT:MOUSEOVER` seems to be a better one.